# Unapply migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have app(example) and there is only one migrations. And I have changed it and I want to unapply and apply it again. If there are many migrations and I want to unapply 0002 migrations, I would use:

```
django-admin migrate example 0001
```

but question is how can I unapply first migration?

Comment: you can very well use fake migration --fake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass 'zero' to unapply all of the migrations for an app.

```
./manage.py migrate example zero
```

You can see the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#migrate

Answer (score 1):

use `zero`

```
django-admin migrate example zero
```

in the doc

> Use the name **zero** to unapply all migrations for an app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
./manage.py migrate <app> zero
```